# Fragment Transaction shows Tabs Fragment below

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm making an app that has launches with a Swiping Tabs Fragment, but I also want to have a Preferences menu using Fragment Transaction. When I press the Settings button in my app, the preferences menu does appear and is interactive, but the layout seems to be transparent showing the Tabs below. Is there anything that can be done to fix this, or is there a better method?

Code that calls the Preferences Menu from the Options:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            break;
        case R.id.logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Main.class));
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new Fragment_Settings()).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Code that calls Tabs Fragments:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new Fragment_Flower();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new Fragment_Overview();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Initialising Transaction in onCreate:

```
startService(new Intent(this, SensorListener.class));
    if (b == null) {
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this
        // fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just set background color in your layout file. It may avoid transparent backgound.